# XCode 7 beta 6 UI Test - cannot pick element in list that is out of view

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

This problem kind of existed previously, but on iPhones only.
I'm testing on iPads and this same problem just came up on beta 6.

If I have a long list of items, I was able to select an item out of the screen view by doing a simple `tap` action on that list item.

Now, when I do that same action, the app does not transition to the next screen and the test does not generate any error.  It thinks as if it has performed correctly and tries to move on to the next step in the UI test.  If I was to manually move the screen view to where the desired list element is, and then perform the `tap` action, it will register and transition to the next screen.

Any ideas how I can go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue in the official release of XCode 7